# Want to perform group by in python where grouped data will come into rows

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I have a data like this:

```
ID Value
1  ABC
1  BCD
1  AKB
2  CAB
2  AIK
3  KIB
```

I want to perform an operation, which will give me something like this:

```
ID Value1 Value2 Value3
1  ABC    BCD    AKB 
2  CAB    AIK
3  KIB
```

I used SAS, where using retain and by we used to get the answer. In Python I'm not getting any way. I know I have to use group by and then something. But don't know what can I use. In Pyspark using group by and collect_list we can get it in array format but I want to do it in Pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `MultiIndex` and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])['Value']
        .unstack()
        .rename(columns=lambda x: 'Value{}'.format(x + 1))
        .reset_index())
```

For python `3.6+` is possible use `f-string`s for rename columns names:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])['Value']
        .unstack()
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Value{x+1}')
        .reset_index())
```

Another idea is create `list`s and new `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(list)
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
       .rename(columns=lambda x: 'Value{}'.format(x + 1))
       .reset_index())
```

```
print (df1)
   ID Value1 Value2 Value3
0   1    ABC    BCD    AKB
1   2    CAB    AIK    NaN
2   3    KIB    NaN    NaN
```

**Performance**: Depends of number of rows and number of unique values of `ID` column:

```
np.random.seed(45)

a = np.sort(np.random.randint(1000, size=10000))
b = np.random.choice(list('abcde'), size=10000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':a, 'Value':b})
#print (df)
```

---

```
In [26]: %%timeit
    ...: (df.set_index(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount()])['Value']
    ...:         .unstack()
    ...:         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Value{x+1}')
    ...:         .reset_index())
    ...: 
8.96 ms ± 628 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [27]: %%timeit
    ...: s = df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(list)
    ...: (pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
    ...:        .rename(columns=lambda x: 'Value{}'.format(x + 1))
    ...:        .reset_index())
    ...: 
    ...: 
105 ms ± 7.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

#jpp solution
In [28]: %%timeit
    ...: def group_gen(df):
    ...:     for key, x in df.groupby('ID'):
    ...:         x = x.set_index('ID').T
    ...:         x.index = pd.Index([key], name='ID')
    ...:         x.columns = [f'Value{i}' for i in range(1, x.shape[1]+1)]
    ...:         yield x
    ...: 
    ...: pd.concat(group_gen(df)).reset_index()
    ...: 

3.23 s ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Accepted. :). I didn't know about this feature earlier.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

One way is to iterate a `groupby` object and concatenate the resultant dataframes:

```
def group_gen(df):
    for key, x in df.groupby('ID'):
        x = x.set_index('ID').T
        x.index = pd.Index([key], name='ID')
        x.columns = [f'Value{i}' for i in range(1, x.shape[1]+1)]
        yield x

res = pd.concat(group_gen(df)).reset_index()

print(res)

   ID Value1 Value2 Value3
0   1    ABC    BCD    AKB
1   2    CAB    AIK    NaN
2   3    KIB    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Working. Awesome.

Comment: @Arun, Sure, np. Don't forget you can upvote / downvote posts that help / don't help!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe called df you have to do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

result = df.groupBy(col('ID')).agg(collect_list(col('Value')).alias('Values'))

how = result.select(max(size(col('Values'))).alias('len')).collect()

for i in range(how[0]['len']):
    result = result.withColumn('Values' + str(i+1), col('Values')[i])
```

Then, result will be like:

```
ID    Values1    Values2    Values3
1     ABC        BCD        AKB
2     CAB        AIK
3     KIB
```

Comment: This is for Pyspark. I want it for Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I haven't seen. I have improved the result for pySpark but i don't know how to do it in Pandas.